# Как увеличить расстояние между блоками текста (bootstrapv4) см скрин?

Tags: css, bootstrap

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/customize.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/time.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/music.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="img/phone.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/support.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/send.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="img/icon/camera.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
                        <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вот так например

```
.media+.media {margin-top:4em}
```